# How do I exclude elements that have a "target" defined (for opening external links in new windows)?

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure if this script is working properly. I do not want to overwrite existing targets. How can I adjust this to exclude links that already have a target defined?

```
$("a[@href^='http://']").not("[@href*='" + window.location.host + "']").attr('target','_blank');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.not("[target]")` to exclude links with a target attribute defined:

```
$("a[href^='http://']").not("[target]")
  .not("[href*='" + window.location.host + "']")
  .attr('target','_blank');
```

Also the syntax of putting `@` in front of attribute selectors was deprecated in 1.2 and removed in 1.3.

Comment: whats the double `..` before `not()`